# One out of all urls is not matching

Tags: django, url-routing

I'm using Django 1.8 and I can't figure out why one particular url isn't getting matched.

The url is `/weapons`. Django is adding a trailing slash to it which I believe is because of the `APPEND_SLASH` option being true by default. Even if I try to reach the url without the slash it will fail then try the slash.

This is the error I get:

[image]

**top level urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url (r'^admin/', include (admin.site.urls)),
    url (r'^', include ('core.urls', namespace = 'core')),
    url (r'^', include ('equipment.urls', namespace = 'equipment')),
]
```

**core urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns [
    url (r'^$', views.index, name = 'index'),
]
```

**equipment urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url (r'^equipment$', views.index, {'type':'index'}, name = 'index'),
    url (r'^weapons$', views.index, {'type':'weapons'}, name = 'weapons'),
    url (r'^armor$', views.index, {'type':'armor'}, name = 'armor'),
    url (r'^accessories$', views.index, {'type':'accessories'}, name = 'accessories'),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a caching issue. I tried it using Ctrl + F5 but it didn't work so I tried the page in Incognito mode which worked. So I used the Developer Tools to reload the page and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
urlpatterns = [
   url (r'^admin/', include (admin.site.urls)),
   url (r'^home/', include ('core.urls', namespace = 'core')),
   url (r'^equipment/', include ('equipment.urls', namespace = 'equipment')),
]
```

and

```
urlpatterns = [
    url (r'^weapons/$', views.index, {'type':'weapons'}, name = 'weapons'), 
]
```

note the `[]` instead of `patterns` in django 1.8

your url would look like:

```
http://localhost:1000/equipment/weapons/
```

which makes sense right?

Comment: Well that's not what I'm currently planning. I just don't understand why just the weapons url isn't working. Every other one works.

Comment: @TreeTree see my update. try `note the [] instead of patterns in django 1.8`

Comment: No difference. \\\\\\\\\\

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove leading `^` from urls in `core/urls.py` and `equipment/urls.py`.